# How to programmatically config iOS' remote notification to just vibrating not playing sound or playing sound without vibrating?

Tags: ios, push-notification, remote-notifications

How can I programmatically config iOS push notification to:

```
not play sound + not vibrate --> OK (Not set `sound` value when push notification)
not play sound + vibrate --> OK (play custom sound (sound with no sound) .i.e: 'sound': 'mute.aiff'))
play sound + vibrate? --> OK (Set `sound` i.e. to `default`)
play sound + not vibrate ???
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use a silent remote notification
add the remote-notification key in  UIBackgroundModes  in your application Info.plist file. 
For more info please check UIBackgroundModes

<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```